# Compare a column in one dataframe with many columns in another dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
     ID       name1
0    ''    'company-1'
1    ''    'company2'
2    ''    'company 3'
```

df2:

```
     ID      name2       name3        name4
0    '1'   'company1'  'company.1'  'company-1'
1    '2'   'company2'  'company.2'  'company-2'
```

I want to compare df1['name1'] to the name columns in df2 and put the ID in df2 in the ID column in df1.

I did this:

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if df1.iloc[i]['name1'] == df2.iloc[j]['name2']:
            df1.iloc[i]['ID'] = df2.iloc[j]['ID']
            break
        elif df1.iloc[i]['name1'] == df2.iloc[j]['name3']:
            df1.iloc[i]['ID'] = df2.iloc[j]['ID']
            break
        elif df1.iloc[i]['name1'] == df2.iloc[j]['name4']:
            df1.iloc[i]['ID'] = df2.iloc[j]['ID']
            break
        else:
            df1[i]['ID'] = ''
```

Expected result would be:

```
     ID       name1
0    '1'    'company-1'
1    '2'    'company2'
2    ''    'company 3'
```

It works, but it's extremely inneficient and takes up to hours. Can you please help me?

I'm sorry if the question doesn't meet the required criteria. It's my first time posting here. I would love some tips regarding that also.

Answer (score 0):

This can be tackled in many ways. You can use a row-wise `apply`, convert the second frame into a mapping/lookup table (Python `dict`), or try joining the two frames. Here's an example of the latter:

```py
import pandas as pd

# The given input data
data_1 = {"ID": ["", "", ""], "name1": ["company-1", "company2", "company 3"]}
data_2 = {"ID"   : ["1", "2"], "name2": ["company1", "company2"], "name3": ["company.1", "company.2"],
          "name4": ["company-1", "company-2"]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

# Changing the second frame into "long format" and only keeping the "ID" and "potential_matches" variables
unpivoted: pd.DataFrame = df_2.melt("ID", value_name="potential_matches")[["ID", "potential_matches"]]

# Merging and tidyiing up
expected = (df_1
            .merge(unpivoted, how="left", left_on=["name1"], right_on=["potential_matches"])
            .drop(columns=["ID_x", "potential_matches"])
            .rename(columns={"ID_y": "ID"})[["ID", "name1"]])

print(expected)
```

If performance is still a problem, you can try matching `name1` on a multi-index of `name2, name3, name4`.

#### Output

| ID | name1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | company-1 |
| 2 | company2 |
| nan | company 3 |